# Call Fancybox from a Google Maps POI

Tags: jquery, fancybox, google-maps-markers

I am building a page which loads gpx track points from a text file as POI's into a Google Maps layer. When the user clicks on a POI they see a thumbnail of a photo taken from that location. What I want to happen is for Fancybox to pop up a larger version of the photo when the user clicks the thumbnail. This doesn't work presumaby because the pop up hasn't been created when the page is loaded. It would appear that I need to add my jQuery code to an Event Listener, but I can't work out how. My non working code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

        var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Physical",
            {type: G_PHYSICAL_MAP}
        );
        var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Streets", // the default
            {numZoomLevels: 20}
        );
        var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Hybrid",
            {type: G_HYBRID_MAP, numZoomLevels: 20}
        );
        var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Satellite",
            {type: G_SATELLITE_MAP, numZoomLevels: 22}
        );

        var pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "My Points",
                { location:"ella_trip_waypoints.txt",
                  projection: map.displayProjection
                });
        map.addLayer(pois);



        map.addLayers([gphy, gmap, ghyb, gsat, pois]);

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-3.98600, 53.12540), 13);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
// Call Fancybox, but how?
});

    }


</script>
```

You can view the page at: http://ian-barton.com/fancybox/google.html

Answer (score -1):

since you are using several instances within the same document, you cannot use the same ID (ID's should be unique within a document) ... use classes instead
see http://fancybox.net/faq No. 7

so you will have on each marker

```
<a class="simpletitle" href="path/image.jpg"><img alt="whatever" src="path/thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

then the script:

```
$("#map").delegate("a.simpletitle", "click", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.fancybox(this);
});
```

that will bind fancybox to present or future elements within that container with id="map"

NOTES:
If you want to add fancybox API options use this format

```
$("#map").delegate("a.simpletitle", "click", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $.fancybox(this,{
  'titlePosition': 'inside'
 });
});
```

the script above works when the content is an image

for other type of content (an external html page for instance) you may use the following script:

```
$("#map").delegate( "a.simpletitle", "click",function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $.fancybox({
  'href': this.href,
  'titlePosition': 'inside',
  'width': 640,
  'height': 360,
  'type':'iframe'
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I have uploaded a modified page with your suggested code mods. In Chrome I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined" when I click the thumbnail.